# Transform the relationship data with weight into a Matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix

Input data format like that: data.txt

```
 col1    col2    weight
 a       b       1
 a       c       2
 a       d       0
 b       c       3
 b       d       0
 c       d       0
```

i want the output data format like that:  result.txt

```
    a  b  c  d
 a  0  1  2  0
 b  1  0  3  0
 c  2  3  0  0
 d  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: It works like this: you try to write a code, then you post it here and we may help with it.

Comment: Show at least what you have coded until now.

Comment: but i got error like that :Exception: Index has duplicates: ['a', 'b']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `pandas` in this way

```
import pandas as pd

# Read your data from a .csv file
df = pd.read_csv('yourdata.csv')

# Pivot table
mat = pd.pivot_table(df,index='col1',columns='col2',values='weight')

# Rebuild the index
index = mat.index.union(mat.columns)

# Build the new full matrix and fill NaN values with 0
mat = mat.reindex(index=index, columns=index).fillna(0)

# Make the matrix symmetric
m = mat + mat.T
```

This returns:

```
   a  b  c  d
a  0  1  2  0
b  1  0  3  0
c  2  3  0  0
d  0  0  0  0
```

EDIT: instead of `pivot_table()` you can also use:

```
mat = df.pivot(index='col1',columns='col2',values='weight')
```

Comment: i have run your code,but have some error like that: TypeError: pivot_table() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index' @  Fabio

Comment: For me it works, what's your python and pandas version?

Comment: Try also `mat = df.pivot(index='col1',columns='col2',values='weight')`

Comment: i got that:`Exception: Index has duplicates: ['a', 'b']`

Comment: @Tursunjan still, for me it works, maybe you have some issues in importing the file? Try format your original .txt file into proper comma separeted values and try importing with the above code.

Answer (score -1):

give a, b, c, d values and set col 1 = i, and col 2 = j. evaluate row by row. For example, row 1, i = 0, j = 1 , weights(i,j) = 1